# Tabs are not working in HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, jquery-tabs

I have small project in which i am using tabs using html css. Please check the demo here: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/1/). But unfortunately my tabs are not working and shoeing as a link. I dont know where i am making small mistake.Any help ? Thank you. Here is my code for HTML CSS and Javascript:

```
body {
    margin : 10px;
    font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
}

#tab-links {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
    margin : 0;
    padding-bottom : 19px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}

#tab-links ul, #tab-links li    {
    display : inline;
    list-style-type : none;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}


#tab-links a:link, #tab-links a:visited {
    background : #E8EBF0;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #666;
    float : left;
    font-size : small;
    font-weight : normal;
    line-height : 14px;
    margin-right : 8px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

#tab-links a:link.active, #tab-links a:visited.active   {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

#tab-links a:hover  {
    color : #f00;
}


body.tabs #tab-links li#nav-1 a, 
body.tabs #tab-links li#nav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

#tab-links #subnav-1,
#tab-links #subnav-2 {
    display : none;
    width: 90%;
}

body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-1, 
body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-2 {
    display : inline;
    left : 10px;
    position : absolute;
    top : 95px;
}

body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-1 a, 
body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border : none;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #999;
    font-size : smaller;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 10px;
    margin-right : 4px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

 #tab-links ul a:hover {
    color : #f00 !important;
}

#contents {
    background : #fff;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top : none;
    clear : both;
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 15px;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

  <div class="tabs">
           <ul id="tab-links">
            <li id="nav-1"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
                    <li id="nav-2"><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>

           </ul>
  </div>


        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                <table id="phones">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                                    </table>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder" checked>
              <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder</label><br>

             <input type="checkbox" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked>
             <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label>
             <button id="submitFilter">Filter</button>
           </div>
        </div>



        <script>
      function makeTable(data){
        var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
          var tbl_row = "",
              currRecord = this;

          $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            if(k==='model'){
              v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['id'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
            } else if (k==='price'){
              v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
            }
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
          })
          tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions() {
     var opts = [];
     $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
         if (this.checked) {
             opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
         }
     });

     return opts;
 }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allBrands;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));

          }
        });
      }    

            $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
      var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

     // Show/Hide Tabs
     $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     // Change/remove current tab to active
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

     e.preventDefault();
 });

      $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
      var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
          updatePhones(opts);
          ("#tab2").show().siblings().hide();
 });


      var allBrands = [];
      $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
      })

      updatePhones();

    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: in css it should be .tab-links

Comment: @suresh thanks but now i want to make current tab active.So how can do that ? The tabs are showing but none of them are active while clicking on it.

Comment: i have added my answer below. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a version of the tabs on the CSS

**HTML**

```
<section id="head">Tabs using CSS3</section>

<section class="tabs">
    <input id="tab_1" type="radio" name="tab" checked="checked" />
    <input id="tab_2" type="radio" name="tab" />
    <input id="tab_3" type="radio" name="tab" />
    <label for="tab_1" id="tab_l1">Tab One</label>
    <label for="tab_2" id="tab_l2">Tab Two</label>
    <label for="tab_3" id="tab_l3">Tab Three</label>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div class="tabs_cont">
        <div id="tab_c1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum, diam vel mollis laoreet, dolor dolor fringilla ligula, at condimentum velit dui a arcu. Integer dapibus sapien eu tellus ullamcorper adipiscing. Aliquam congue interdum venenatis. Sed ornare pulvinar commodo. Vivamus faucibus velit enim. Nulla at lorem felis, quis condimentum felis. Nulla luctus consequat tellus at faucibus. Donec et felis at lacus lobortis luctus. In quis nisl metus. Aenean ultricies augue in sem elementum consequat. Vestibulum convallis sollicitudin venenatis. Aliquam et enim lacus.</p>
            <p>Integer sapien erat, convallis pulvinar tempor sit amet, placerat in metus. Mauris volutpat porttitor magna euismod sodales. Ut quis consequat augue. Curabitur ut neque sed purus accumsan feugiat sed sit amet lacus. Donec blandit scelerisque metus, nec consectetur odio varius et. Nulla nibh nibh, pellentesque et mattis eget, rutrum porttitor nulla. Aliquam pharetra augue quis nisl luctus sit amet convallis augue consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab_c2">
            <p>Integer sapien erat, convallis pulvinar tempor sit amet, placerat in metus. Mauris volutpat porttitor magna euismod sodales. Ut quis consequat augue. Curabitur ut neque sed purus accumsan feugiat sed sit amet lacus. Donec blandit scelerisque metus, nec consectetur odio varius et. Nulla nibh nibh, pellentesque et mattis eget, rutrum porttitor nulla. Aliquam pharetra augue quis nisl luctus sit amet convallis augue consequat.</p>
            <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean dictum, sapien sed tincidunt condimentum, turpis purus sollicitudin urna, eget ullamcorper quam libero mattis odio. Nulla eget augue est, vitae egestas nibh. Morbi eu neque sed ante gravida vestibulum et a risus. Nullam ultrices eleifend augue id lacinia. Cras at sapien urna, sit amet pharetra neque. Praesent non sem eu justo malesuada vestibulum id ac nisl. Cras accumsan velit eget quam dictum commodo. Donec iaculis ipsum eu arcu aliquet pellentesque. Donec non velit nec arcu auctor egestas. Etiam consectetur tellus sed eros convallis placerat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab_c3">
            <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean dictum, sapien sed tincidunt condimentum, turpis purus sollicitudin urna, eget ullamcorper quam libero mattis odio. Nulla eget augue est, vitae egestas nibh. Morbi eu neque sed ante gravida vestibulum et a risus. Nullam ultrices eleifend augue id lacinia. Cras at sapien urna, sit amet pharetra neque. Praesent non sem eu justo malesuada vestibulum id ac nisl. Cras accumsan velit eget quam dictum commodo. Donec iaculis ipsum eu arcu aliquet pellentesque. Donec non velit nec arcu auctor egestas. Etiam consectetur tellus sed eros convallis placerat.</p>
            <p>Vivamus imperdiet varius urna, sed ullamcorper enim interdum ac. Quisque nibh risus, auctor quis ultricies non, ultricies ut purus. Mauris vitae augue erat. Praesent blandit diam at est laoreet suscipit. Vivamus mauris quam, gravida ultricies sodales sit amet, commodo a eros. Vestibulum varius sollicitudin nisl, vitae sollicitudin dolor aliquet in. Duis et nulla mi. Morbi sit amet mi nisl. Cras eu augue libero. Cras laoreet ligula in augue tempus accumsan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #eff0f4 4%, #dddee0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(4%,#eff0f4), color-stop(100%,#dddee0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eff0f4 4%,#dddee0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eff0f4 4%,#dddee0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eff0f4 4%,#dddee0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#eff0f4 4%,#dddee0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddee0',GradientType=0 );
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0;
    z-index: 1;}
.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;}
#tab_1:checked  ~ #tab_l1,
#tab_2:checked  ~ #tab_l2,
#tab_3:checked  ~ #tab_l3 {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;}

.tabs_cont {
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 20px 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 230px;}
.tabs_cont > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;}

#tab_1:checked ~ .tabs_cont #tab_c1,
#tab_2:checked ~ .tabs_cont #tab_c2,
#tab_3:checked ~ .tabs_cont #tab_c3 {
    position: static;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;}
```

[THIS DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrBup)

Comment: hi but i the demo u showede me will be having problem in browsers support

Comment: under which browsers need support?

Comment: I am sorry but cant u show me the problem in my version of tabs. I have to make lot of changes if i used your version.I have also used javascript for this tabs so i have to make changes in that too.

Comment: I suggested as an alternative without using JS, sorry that my version you have not approached

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your CSS and jquery. Also I have applied the selected tab styles. Check the below jsfiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
function makeTable(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
      var tbl_row = "",
          currRecord = this;

      $.each(this, function(k , v) {
        if(k==='model'){
          v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['id'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
        } else if (k==='price'){
          v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
        }
        tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
      })
      tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })

    return tbl_body;
  }

  function getPhoneFilterOptions() {
 var opts = [];
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
         opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
     }
 });

 return opts;
 }

  function updatePhones(opts){
    if(!opts || !opts.length){
      opts = allBrands;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(records){
        $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));

      }
    });
  }    

        $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
 var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
// alert('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue);
 // Show/Hide Tabs

 $('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

 // Change/remove current tab to active
 $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

 e.preventDefault();
 });

  $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
 var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
      updatePhones(opts);
      ("#tab2").show().siblings().hide();
 });


  var allBrands = [];
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
  })

  updatePhones();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/18/

Comment: thanks very much now its working fine. Just a small help currently when i run this code the tab1 is not getting activate by defualt.So how can i activate it ? You can check in fiddle that none of the tab is active currently.I have to click it to active it.

Comment: Thanks suresh its working now. If you have time just one more small request.I am trying to provide reference to tabs.So in tab2 when u click on filter button it should go to tab1. So how can i provide such reference ?

Comment: :) If you are ok with this answer give one up vote for me. Upadated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/18/

Comment: Hi Suresh i coud have definately voted you but i have just joined this forum and i dont have enough reputation to vote u up. Sorry friend :( But i marked this as a answer :(